# Opening Brackets Do Not Format to Paragraphs in Visual Editor

Tags: editor

I'm having issues with paragraphs in the visual editor.

So let's say I create a blockquote, type the first line, hit enter. It makes a new paragraph. Shift + enter makes a new line. Just like usual, this all works.

But for some reason, whenever my paragraph or line starts with a bracket "[", it does not make a new paragraph. It will add a closing paragraph tag where it should go, but not an opening paragraph tag. This is a major problem for me, as I run a Pokemon card website, and to denote card attack costs, we use brackets. The card attack costs always start at the beginning of a line. So I'm stuck. I could just go into text mode to fix it, but this would be a major hassle since we have to post dozens of card spoilers as quickly as possible when major news breaks.

Anyone know how I can fix this? I think it may be because it's expecting a shortcode or something.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue with a default theme and no plugins activated, but I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're describing. Paragraph tags get added when content is output, not within the editor, so I'm not sure how you're fixing things in text mode. Anyway, verify that it's not a theme or plugin issue.